# Борьба с addAttachment в PHPMail

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

Здравия всем, уважаемые программисты.
В модуле joomla 3 пытаюсь добавить в форму обратной связи поле с добавлением файла. 
Приходит письмо, и как бы есть вложение, но там сплошные цифры и буквы без расширения и 0кб.
Вот это дописал

```
 <?php $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']));
    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded-file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);

    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
    $mailSender->addAttachment($uploadfile); ?>

<label>
<input class="uploaded-file" id="uploaded-file" type="file" name="uploaded-file"/>
<span id="text_fileup">Выбрать файл</span>
</label>
```

Знаю чего-то не хватает, пересмотрел многое, но так и не понял чего там надо.
Спасибо за ранее, кто подскажет правильное решение. +100500 в карму Вам.✌

Comment: Как я понял вы используете PHPMailer. Вроде все по документации, только непонятно, в одном месте у вас `$mail` в другом `$mailSender`

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, там в модуле так было $mailSender, это я сторонний код в примере подсмотрел. но потом исправил $mail на $mailSender, все равно не приходят с файлом..
Но позже я нашел код от этого модуля и сейчас теперь так:

Comment: '$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$uploadext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowedext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf');
$allowedattachment = false;
foreach ($allowedext as $extension) {
if ($extension == $uploadext) {
$allowedattachment = true;
}
}'

Comment: $mailSender->setSubject($mySubject);
    $mailSender->setBody($myMessage);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $fileName)){
 if ($allowedattachment == true) {
  $mailSender->addAttachment($tmpName, $fileName);
 }

Comment: Однако, все равно не приходит вложение вообще никакое

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение с похожим кодом на
[github.com](https://github.com/sosojni/joomla-contact-module)

Спасибо большое Stjepan Osojnički.

Правда надо некоторые настройки в модуле сделать, что бы отправлялось, видимо модуль не дописан. А именно:

Exact URL -  выкл

Disable HTTPS - вкл

Fixed URL - выкл